# Making a UITableView scroll when text field is selected

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, keyboard, scroll

After a lot of trial and error, I'm giving up and asking the question. I've seen a lot of people with similar problems but can't get all the answers to work right.

I have a `UITableView` which is composed of custom cells. The cells are made of 5 text fields next to each other (sort of like a grid).

When I try to scroll and edit the cells at the bottom of the `UITableView`, I can't manage to get my cells properly positioned above the keyboard.

I have seen many answers talking about changing view sizes,etc... but none of them has worked nicely so far.

Could anybody clarify the "right" way to do this with a concrete code example?

Comment: This Applle documentation outlines the steps to implement a solution for this question. [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: @ChrisP That link states it has not been updated for iOS 4.0

Comment: This code can be helpful: 
https://gist.github.com/TimMedcalf/9505416

Comment: Follow below Url, it will work:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922266/uitableview-custom-cell-auto-scroll-when-text-field-is-tapped-swift-3/48923632#48923632

Answer (score 129):

If you use UITableViewController instead of UIViewController, it will automatically do so.

Comment: Did you try and found that not working? Or is the solution too simple for you to believe? Just extend the UITableViewController instead of UIViewController and the cell containing the textfields will scroll above the keyboard whenever the textfields become the first responder. No extra code needed.

Comment: This solved it for me too. You should refactor your IB layout so that your table is the TVC's view. If you need it in a container view, you should rethink your approach or you'll end up using a hack-around.

Comment: Yes, but especially on the iPad we need a way to do this that doesn't involve the UITableViewController.

Comment: To clarify, its not a reasonable answer to say that every single time you use a tableview it needs to be full screen, especially on an iPad. There are hordes of examples of great apps that don't do that. For instance, many of Apple's own, including the Contacts app on the iPad.

Comment: This should be at the top. while there maybe a legitimate need for deriving from UIViewController with a table view. but if u've a form like situation this is the easiest thing that works out of the box

Comment: For me Its not working. it will dependent any parent viewController? because UITabBarController One of the ViewController Is UINavigationController initWithRootViewController(rootviewController is UITableViewController).

Comment: Hmm, yeah, it doesn't seem to work for me either. Seems buggy.

Comment: Doesn't work 100% of the time. I had autoscrolling working and now all of a sudden it refuses to work...

Comment: I'm having issues with this too. It used to work automagically, but now doesn't :(

Comment: It won't work if you override [super viewWillAppear:YES]. Other than that, it should work.

Comment: It does not work properly if you have more than one text field or text view in the cell, because it attempts to focus on the cell and not on the text view or text field itself.

Comment: If you override viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated, don't forget to call [super viewWillAppear:animated]; :)

Comment: its working, but when i select the textfield and scroll the table its hide behind of keyboard , and then i will insert text then it not visible .

Comment: Not working accurately for me. Sometimes the text field in my custom table view cell gets scrolled off the top of the screen or under the navigation bar.

Comment: Its brilliant answer. Perfectly worked for me. I have a query, how [super viewWIllAppear:animated] statement made it work when I override viewWillAppear method ? Is there any logic behind this ?

Comment: If you have multiple sections go with grouped tableview, else it won't work scrolling properly.

Comment: This won't work correctly if you have a large cell that is greater than the screen height.

Answer (score 94):

The function that does the scrolling could be much simpler:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
        cell = (UITableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview;

    } else {
        // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
        cell = (UITableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview.superview; 
       // TextField -> UITableVieCellContentView -> (in iOS 7!)ScrollView -> Cell!
    }
    [tView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[tView indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

That's it. No calculations at all.

Comment: I don't think that's going to match the Apple behaviour where the text field responder is centred within the visible area of the table view.

Comment: And why not?! Just replace UITableViewScrollPositionTop with UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle. You just need to rescale the UITableView to adjust the visible area, of course.

Comment: Very useful ! You can even make it more independant by getting the table view that way: UITableView *tView = (UITableView*) [cell superview];

Comment: You don't update the tableView frame. Then, the scrollBars and the scrolling behavior are wrong when the keyboard is shown. See my solution.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if a UITableViewController has taken care of the table view resizing when the keyboard is shown: the controller reduces the visible size with a `contentInset`, which apparently is not taken into account when asking for `visibleRows` or `indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

Comment: Doesn't work for the last few rows of table view.  The keyboard will still obscure all rows that can not be scrolled above the keyboard.

Comment: To get the auto-scroll behavior to work on the last few rows of the table, detect when these rows begin editing, and add a footer to the end of the tableview with a blank view of a certain height. This will allow the tableview to scroll the cells to the correct place.

Comment: Getting to the cell through a chain of calls to superview is unreliable, unless you make sure you are actually getting to the cell. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17757851/1371070 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17758021/1371070

Comment: Instead of deep diving for superview's, make a subclass of `UITextField` and take a property of type your cell, `UITableViewCell`. Reference cell to textfield (may be in `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method). And you can use it here, like this, `[tView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[tView indexPathForCell:textfield.cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];`

Comment: @Sammio2 I tried your approach and it works fine. But the problem now is I want to remove that footer view when I finish Editing

Answer (score 71):

I'm doing something very similar it's generic, no need to compute something specific for your code.
Just check the remarks on the code:

In MyUIViewController.h

```
@interface MyUIViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
     UITableView *myTableView;
     UITextField *actifText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *actifText;

- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
- (IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note;
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note;

@end
```

In MyUIViewController.m

```
@implementation MyUIViewController

@synthesize myTableView;
@synthesize actifText;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // Register notification when the keyboard will be show
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                          name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                          object:nil];

    // Register notification when the keyboard will be hide
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                          name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                          object:nil];
}

// To be link with your TextField event "Editing Did Begin"
//  memoryze the current TextField
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.actifText = textField;
}

// To be link with your TextField event "Editing Did End"
//  release current TextField
- (IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.actifText = nil;
}

-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    // Get the keyboard size
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    // Detect orientation
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGRect frame = self.myTableView.frame;

    // Start animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

    // Reduce size of the Table view 
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.height;
    else 
        frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.width;

    // Apply new size of table view
    self.myTableView.frame = frame;

    // Scroll the table view to see the TextField just above the keyboard
    if (self.actifText)
      {
        CGRect textFieldRect = [self.myTableView convertRect:self.actifText.bounds fromView:self.actifText];
        [self.myTableView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:NO];
      }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
    // Get the keyboard size
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    // Detect orientation
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGRect frame = self.myTableView.frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

    // Increase size of the Table view 
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.height;
    else 
        frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.width;

    // Apply new size of table view
    self.myTableView.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

---

### Swift 1.2+ version:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var activeText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"),
            name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"),
            name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeText = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeText = nil
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(note: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (note.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            var frame = tableView.frame
            UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
            UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
            UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
            frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
            tableView.frame = frame
            if activeText != nil {
                let rect = tableView.convertRect(activeText.bounds, fromView: activeText)
                tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
            }
            UIView.commitAnimations()
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(note: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (note.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            var frame = tableView.frame
            UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
            UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
            UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
            frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height
            tableView.frame = frame
            UIView.commitAnimations()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using the notifications and getting the keyboard height while incorporating device orientation was awesome, thanks for that! the scrolling part did not work for me for some reason, so i had to use this: `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: indexPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated: YES];`

Comment: This is the best answer here I think. Very clean. Only two things:1) your viewDidLoad is not calling [super viewDidLoad] and 2) I had to had in some tabbar math on the frame.size.height lines. Otherwise perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Here's the modification toxaq describes: `MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; CGFloat tabBarHeight = appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;`  Then subtract tabBarHeight from keyboard height wherever you use keyboard height.

Comment: This solution only works on iOS ≥ 3.2. `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` is not available on older iOS versions. See my solution below that works across all current iOS releases ≥ 3.0.

Comment: All the way champ. Works grt. Thanks :)

Comment: I needed to adapt this code so that a search bar at the bottom of the `tableView` would move up when the keyboard showed, and this worked great, thank you.

Comment: I'm using a tabbar controller, do you know what do I need to add to the code above to make it work for the scrollView inside the child controller?

Comment: What will happen if user select textfield of 1st row, keyboard appear and user scroll the table and select the other textfield of table . view being disappear .

Comment: If user tap on textfield its working perfect. but if user tap on another textfield without pressing return key then its reduce size of tableview.

Comment: @BhavinRamani agreed. I added a simple boolean property to remember if the keyboard is already being displayed or not, and skip code re-execution when unnecessary.

Comment: it work for me, the best answer ever seen. but it has a white bar appear on the keyboard. The code didn't add any extra height or tapbar view...it is wired.

Comment: keyboard size worked for me only for the first time. so i use this to get the keyboard rect     CGRect keyboardBounds = [[[note userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
i am also ignoring the if (self.actifText) part and only shifting the frame of table.

Comment: Brilliant answer, although I suggest changing the `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to `UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

Comment: Notes: 1. Add those observers in `viewDidAppear`, then remove those observers in `viewDidDisappear`. 2. change `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` 3. don't reassign the `tableView.frame` (just delete `tableView.frame = frame`).

Comment: @BhavinRamani just delete the `tableView.frame = frame`, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 49):

The simplest solution for **Swift 3**, based on [Bartłomiej Semańczyk solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197147/1064438):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CreateEditRitualViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CreateEditRitualViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

// MARK: Keyboard Notifications

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight, 0)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        // For some reason adding inset in keyboardWillShow is animated by itself but removing is not, that's why we have to use animateWithDuration here
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    })
}
```

Comment: A minor detail... Using `Notification` instead of `NSNotification` would be more "Swift 3-y" :-)

Comment: This will help with repositioning if there is a navbar -- surround UIView.animate with this if let -- if let frame = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame {
                        let y = frame.size.height + frame.origin.y }

Comment: when rotation happens there is glitch in the loading and some cell disappears when tableview is scrolled manully

Comment: Good solution thanks!  Note - don't need to do the removeObserver anymore.

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem but noticed that it appears only in one view. So I began to look for the differences in the controllers.

I found out that the scrolling behavior is set in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` of the super instance.

So be sure to implement like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // your code
}
```

And it doesn't matter if you use `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`; checked it by putting a `UITableView` as a subview of self.view in the `UIViewController`. It was the same behavior. The view didn't allow to scroll if the call `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` was missing.

Comment: This worked excellently. I was wondering why people said UITableView would do it for me and this solved it. Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem as well, this answer should make it up to the top!

Comment: I lost so much time trying to figure it out on my own... thanks ;)

Comment: +1 was starting to cry a little, i had that line but needed also [tableViewController viewWillAppear:animated]; because i'm adding a UITableViewController to a UIViewController. no more tears :)

Answer (score 41):

i may have missed this, as i didn't read the whole post here, but what i came up with seems deceptively simple.  i haven't put this through the wringer, testing in all situations, but it seems like it should work just fine.

simply adjust the contentInset of the tableview by the height of the keyboard, and then scroll the cell to the bottom:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.myTableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    [self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.currentField.indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

and of course

```
- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^(void) 
    {
        self.myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        self.myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }];
}
```

is this too simple?  am i missing something?  so far it is working for me fine, but as i said, i haven't put it through the wringer...

Comment: IMO, this is the best solution. Only thing I'd change is your hardcoded duration to `[aNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]`

Comment: It is very simple. But one issue I find is that it will not animate the change in `contentInset` and sharply change the scroll bounds.

Comment: This one worked the best for me, however, a few issues. 1) I don't know where you could get "currentField.indexPath", so I had to save the indexPath.row as the field's tag and create the indexPath later. 2) Doesn't work for rows at the top of the table, it scrolls them off screen. Had to add some code to only scroll if the currentField's indexPath is greater than what can fit on screen. 3) had to use kbSize.Width (instead of height) on iPad if it's landscape

Comment: sorry, we become so used to our own code that we forget sometimes, eh?  currentField is the current text field i'm working with, and indexPath is an extension that i added to the class that simply adds an NSIndexPath so i know what cell this is in.

Comment: This is the way to go, not moving frames around just modifying table properties.

Comment: This works for me, don't even need the `[self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath...` bit either

Answer (score 35):

I think I've come up with the solution to match the behaviour of Apple's apps.

First, in your viewWillAppear: subscribe to the keyboard notifications, so you know when the keyboard will show and hide, and the system will tell you the size of the keyboard, but dont' forget to unregister in your viewWillDisappear:.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
           name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
         object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
           name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
         object:nil];
```

Implement the methods similar to the below so that you adjust the size of your tableView to match the visible area once the keyboard shows. Here I'm tracking the state of the keyboard separately so I can choose when to set the tableView back to full height myself, since you get these notifications on every field change. Don't forget to implement keyboardWillHide: and choose somewhere appropriate to fix your tableView size.

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.height;
    if (keyboardIsShowing == NO)
    {
        keyboardIsShowing = YES;
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.size.height -= keyboardHeight;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Now here's the scrolling bit, we work out a few sizes first, then we see where we are in the visible area, and set the rect we want to scroll to to be either the half view above or below the middle of the text field based on where it is in the view. In this case, we have an array of UITextFields and an enum that keeps track of them, so multiplying the rowHeight by the row number gives us the actual offset of the frame within this outer view.

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect frame = textField.frame;
    CGFloat rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
    if (textField == textFields[CELL_FIELD_ONE])
    {
        frame.origin.y += rowHeight * CELL_FIELD_ONE;
    }
    else if (textField == textFields[CELL_FIELD_TWO])
    {
        frame.origin.y += rowHeight * CELL_FIELD_TWO;
    }
    else if (textField == textFields[CELL_FIELD_THREE])
    {
        frame.origin.y += rowHeight * CELL_FIELD_THREE;
    }
    else if (textField == textFields[CELL_FIELD_FOUR])
    {
        frame.origin.y += rowHeight * CELL_FIELD_FOUR;
    }
    CGFloat viewHeight = self.tableView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat halfHeight = viewHeight / 2;
    CGFloat midpoint = frame.origin.y + (textField.frame.size.height / 2);
    if (midpoint < halfHeight)
    {
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size.height = midpoint;
    }
    else
    {
        frame.origin.y = midpoint;
        frame.size.height = midpoint;
    }
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

This seems to work quite nicely.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: `UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey` is deprecated as of iOS 3.2. See my solution below that works across all current iOS releases ≥ 3.0. /@iPhoneDev

Comment: This was more complicated than it needed to be. @user91083's answer was simple and works.

Comment: There's a small problem in this solution. keyboardWillShow is called AFTER textFieldDidBeginEditing, so when we want to scroll to some cell, tableView's frame hasn't changed yet, so it won't work

Answer (score 35):

If you can use `UITableViewController`, you get the functionality for free. Sometimes, however, this is not an option, specifically if you need multiple views not just the `UITableView`.

Some of the solutions presented here don't work on iOS ≥4, some don't work on iPad or in landscape mode, some don't work for Bluetooth keyboards (where we don't want any scrolling), some don't work when switching between multiple text fields. So if you choose any solution, make sure to test these cases. This is the solution we <strike>use</strike> **used** in [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/):

```
- (void)_keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if (self.navigationController.topViewController == self) {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

        // we don't use SDK constants here to be universally compatible with all SDKs ≥ 3.0
        NSValue* keyboardFrameValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"];
        if (!keyboardFrameValue) {
            keyboardFrameValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"];
        }

        // Reduce the tableView height by the part of the keyboard that actually covers the tableView
        CGRect windowRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].bounds;
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == self.interfaceOrientation ||UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == self.interfaceOrientation ) {
            windowRect = IASKCGRectSwap(windowRect);
        }
        CGRect viewRectAbsolute = [_tableView convertRect:_tableView.bounds toView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == self.interfaceOrientation ||UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == self.interfaceOrientation ) {
            viewRectAbsolute = IASKCGRectSwap(viewRectAbsolute);
        }
        CGRect frame = _tableView.frame;
        frame.size.height -= [keyboardFrameValue CGRectValue].size.height - CGRectGetMaxY(windowRect) + CGRectGetMaxY(viewRectAbsolute);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
        _tableView.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        UITableViewCell *textFieldCell = (id)((UITextField *)self.currentFirstResponder).superview.superview;
        NSIndexPath *textFieldIndexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:textFieldCell];

        // iOS 3 sends hide and show notifications right after each other
        // when switching between textFields, so cancel -scrollToOldPosition requests
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

        [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:textFieldIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void) scrollToOldPosition {
  [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_topmostRowBeforeKeyboardWasShown atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

- (void)_keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if (self.navigationController.topViewController == self) {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
        _tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToOldPosition) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}
```

Here's the [full code of the class](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/blob/9f32e0c6fc6aa66c10595aaf2ad99d040270ce14/InAppSettingsKit/Controllers/IASKAppSettingsViewController.m) in InAppSettingsKit. To test it, use the "Complete List" child pane where you can test the scenarios mentioned above.

Comment: I don't know if it's useful to use strings instead of constants, because if Apple comes to the idea to change the String internally for some reasons, your solution is not working anymore. Likewise you did not get an warning when it becomes deprecated.I think

Comment: @iPortable: it's not ideal, I know. Can you suggest a better solution that runs on all versions ≥3.0?

Comment: Works like charm, but not for UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown. Then the calculation of the height reduction has to be based upside down as well: CGFloat reduceHeight = keyboardRect.size.height - ( CGRectGetMinY(viewRectAbsolute) - CGRectGetMinY(windowRect));

Comment: This has very noticeable visual glitches on my iPad and the Simulator (4.3). Too noticeable to use. :(

Comment: I like that this solution will account for a toolbar at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: IASK now seems to use UITableViewController's built-in automatic scrolling.

Comment: Emile: right, which is perfectly fine if you're having just one table view in your ViewController. There are situations however, where you can't use `UITableViewController`, specifically if you've multiple views.

Answer (score 27):

The simplest solution for **Swift**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    searchBar?.becomeFirstResponder()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size.height {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight, 0)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { self.table_create_issue.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) })
    // For some reason adding inset in keyboardWillShow is animated by itself but removing is not, that's why we have to use animateWithDuration here
    }
```

**For Swift 4.2 or greater**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar?.becomeFirstResponder()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size.height
            accountSettingsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0)
        
    }
}
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { self.accountSettingsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) })}
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, minimum calculations needed. I've added some code that restores table insets back to make this answer finished.

Comment: Best solution thanks. I've post a Swift 3 version here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41040630/1064438

Comment: Super perfect solution ever seen, I tried others but has some issues. You solution work perfect on ios 10.2.

Answer (score 8):

I hope you guys already got a solution reading all those. But I found my solution as follows. I am expecting that you already have a cell with `UITextField`. So on preparing just keep the row index into the text field's tag.

```
cell.textField.tag = IndexPath.row;
```

Create an `activeTextField`, instance of `UITextField` with global scope as below:

```
@interface EditViewController (){

    UITextField *activeTextField;

}
```

So, now you just copy paste my code at the end. And also don't forget to add `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
#pragma mark - TextField Delegation

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    activeTextField = textField;

    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    activeTextField = nil;

}
```

Registers keyboard `notifications`

```
#pragma mark - Keyboard Activity

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications

{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)

                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)

                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];



}
```

Handles Keyboard `Notifications`:

Called when the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is sent.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);

    [self.tableView setContentInset:contentInsets];

    [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:contentInsets];

    NSIndexPath *currentRowIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:activeTextField.tag inSection:0];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:currentRowIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

}
```

Called when the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is sent

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    [self.tableView setContentInset:contentInsets];

    [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:contentInsets];

}
```

Now one thing is left, Call the `registerForKeyboardNotifications` method in to `ViewDidLoad` method as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Registering keyboard notification

    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];

    // Your codes here...

}
```

You are done, hope your `textFields` will no longer hidden by the keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

Combining and filling in the blanks from several answers (in particular Ortwin Gentz, user 98013) and another post, this will work out of the box for SDK 4.3 on an iPad in Portrait or Landscape mode:

```
@implementation UIView (FindFirstResponder)
- (UIResponder *)findFirstResponder
{
  if (self.isFirstResponder) {        
    return self;     
  }

  for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
    UIResponder *firstResponder = [subView findFirstResponder];
    if (firstResponder != nil) {
      return firstResponder;
    }
  }

  return nil;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (UIResponder *)currentFirstResponder {
  return [self.view findFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)editingEnded:sender {
  [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[textField superview] superview];
  [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[_tableView indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
  if ([self currentFirstResponder] != nil) {
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    // we don't use SDK constants here to be universally compatible with all SDKs ≥ 3.0
    NSValue* keyboardFrameValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"];
    if (!keyboardFrameValue) {
      keyboardFrameValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"];
    }

    // Reduce the tableView height by the part of the keyboard that actually covers the tableView
    CGRect windowRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].bounds;
    CGRect viewRectAbsolute = [_tableView convertRect:_tableView.bounds toView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
    CGRect frame = _tableView.frame;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == self.interfaceOrientation ||UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == self.interfaceOrientation ) {
      windowRect = CGRectMake(windowRect.origin.y, windowRect.origin.x, windowRect.size.height, windowRect.size.width);
      viewRectAbsolute = CGRectMake(viewRectAbsolute.origin.y, viewRectAbsolute.origin.x, viewRectAbsolute.size.height, viewRectAbsolute.size.width);
    }
    frame.size.height -= [keyboardFrameValue CGRectValue].size.height - CGRectGetMaxY(windowRect) + CGRectGetMaxY(viewRectAbsolute);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
    _tableView.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    UITableViewCell *textFieldCell = (id)((UITextField *)self.currentFirstResponder).superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *textFieldIndexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:textFieldCell];

    // iOS 3 sends hide and show notifications right after each other
    // when switching between textFields, so cancel -scrollToOldPosition requests
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    _topmostRowBeforeKeyboardWasShown = [[_tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
    [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:textFieldIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
  }
}

- (void) scrollToOldPosition {
  [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_topmostRowBeforeKeyboardWasShown atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
  if ([self currentFirstResponder] != nil) {

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
    _tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToOldPosition) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
  }
}   

@end
```

Comment: I used this code in iOS 4.x just fine, but in iOS5 it crashes in scrollToOldPosition because _topmostRowBeforeKeyboardWasShown is freed at that time already. Not sure what the solution is yet. Probably remember the index instead of the object.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a uitableview to place your textfields ([from Jeff Lamarche](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/all-generic-controllers-to-date-zip.html)), you can just scroll the tableview using the delegate method like so.

(Note: my text fields are stored in an array with the same index as there row in the tableview)

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {

        int index;
        for(UITextField *aField in textFields){

            if (textField == aField){
                index = [textFields indexOfObject:aField]-1;
            }
        }

         if(index >= 0) 
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

        [super textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField];
    }
```

Comment: You don't update the tableView frame. Then, the scrollBars and the scrolling behavior are wrong when the keyboard is shown. See my solution.

Answer (score 5):

Keyboard notifications work, but Apple's sample code for that assumes that the scroll view is the root view of the window. This is usually not the case. You have to compensate for tab bars, etc., to get the right offset.

It is easier than it sounds. Here is the code I use in a UITableViewController. It has two instance variables, hiddenRect and keyboardShown.

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    if (keyboardShown)
        return;

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    // Get the frame of the keyboard.
    NSValue *centerValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey];
    NSValue *boundsValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
    CGPoint keyboardCenter = [centerValue CGPointValue];
    CGRect keyboardBounds = [boundsValue CGRectValue];
    CGPoint keyboardOrigin = CGPointMake(keyboardCenter.x - keyboardBounds.size.width / 2.0,
                                         keyboardCenter.y - keyboardBounds.size.height / 2.0);
    CGRect keyboardScreenFrame = { keyboardOrigin, keyboardBounds.size };


    // Resize the scroll view.
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *) self.tableView;
    CGRect viewFrame = scrollView.frame;
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [scrollView.superview convertRect:keyboardScreenFrame fromView:nil];
    hiddenRect = CGRectIntersection(viewFrame, keyboardFrame);

    CGRect remainder, slice;
    CGRectDivide(viewFrame, &slice, &remainder, CGRectGetHeight(hiddenRect), CGRectMaxYEdge);
    scrollView.frame = remainder;

    // Scroll the active text field into view.
    CGRect textFieldRect = [/* selected cell */ frame];
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];

    keyboardShown = YES;
}


// Called when the UIKeyboardDidHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    // Reset the height of the scroll view to its original value
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *) self.tableView;
    CGRect viewFrame = [scrollView frame];
    scrollView.frame = CGRectUnion(viewFrame, hiddenRect);

    keyboardShown = NO;
}
```

Comment: `UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey` are deprecated as of iOS 3.2. See my solution below that works across all current iOS releases ≥ 3.0.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `Three20`, then use the `autoresizesForKeyboard` property. Just set in the your view controller's `-initWithNibName:bundle` method

```
self.autoresizesForKeyboard = YES
```

This takes care of:

1. Listening for keyboard notifications and adjusting the table view's frame
2. Scrolling to the first responder

Done and done.

Comment: what is Three20 here? Can you specify that?

Answer (score 5):

My approach:

I first subclass UITextField and add an indexPath property. In the cellFor... Method i hand over the indexPath property.

Then I add following code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:textField.indexPath];

CGPoint cellPoint = [cell convertPoint:textField.center toView:self.tableView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^(void){self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, cellPoint.y-50);}];
```

to the textFieldShould/WillBegin...etc.

When the Keyboard disappears you have to reverse it with:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^(void){self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);}];
```

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 4.2 complete solution

I've created [GIST with set of protocols](https://gist.github.com/Sorix/2c08b36f020658d153c57bbed6f028a8) that simplifies work with adding extra space when keyboard is shown, hidden or changed.

**Features**:

- Correctly works with keyboard frame changes (e.g. keyboard height changes like emojii → normal keyboard).
- TabBar & ToolBar support for UITableView example (at other examples you receive incorrect insets).
- Dynamic animation duration (not hard-coded).
- Protocol-oriented approach that could be easily modified for you purposes.

#### Usage

Basic usage example in view controller that contains some scroll view (table view is supported also of course).

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    addKeyboardFrameChangesObserver()
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    removeKeyboardFrameChangesObserver()
  }
}

extension SomeViewController: ModifableInsetsOnKeyboardFrameChanges {
  var scrollViewToModify: UIScrollView { return scrollView }
}
```

#### Core: frame changes observer

Protocol `KeyboardChangeFrameObserver` will fire event each time keyboard frame was changed (including showing, hiding, frame changing).

1. Call `addKeyboardFrameChangesObserver()` at `viewWillAppear()` or similar method.
2. Call `removeKeyboardFrameChangesObserver()` at `viewWillDisappear()` or similar method.

#### Implementation: scrolling view

`ModifableInsetsOnKeyboardFrameChanges` protocol adds `UIScrollView` support to core protocol. It changes scroll view's insets when keyboard frame is changed.

Your class needs to set scroll view, one's insets will be increased / decreased on keyboard frame changes.

```
var scrollViewToModify: UIScrollView { get }
```

Answer (score 4):

A more stream-lined solution.  It slips into the UITextField delegate methods, so it doesn't require messing w/ UIKeyboard notifications.

Implementation notes:

kSettingsRowHeight -- the height of a UITableViewCell.

offsetTarget and offsetThreshold are baed off of kSettingsRowHeight.  If you use a different row height, set those values to point's y property.  [alt: calculate the row offset in a different manner.]

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
CGFloat offsetTarget    = 113.0f; // 3rd row
CGFloat offsetThreshold = 248.0f; // 6th row (i.e. 2nd-to-last row)

CGPoint point = [self.tableView convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:textField];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
if (point.y > offsetThreshold) {
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                      offsetTarget - point.y + kSettingsRowHeight,
                      frame.size.width,
                      frame.size.height);
} else if (point.y > offsetTarget) {
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                      offsetTarget - point.y,
                      frame.size.width,
                      frame.size.height);
} else {
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                      0.0f,
                      frame.size.width,
                      frame.size.height);
}

[UIView commitAnimations];

return YES;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                  0.0f,
                  frame.size.width,
                  frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Use `UITextField's` `delegate` method :

### Swift

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> bool {
  let txtFieldPosition = textField.convertPoint(textField.bounds.origin, toView: yourTableViewHere)
  let indexPath = yourTablViewHere.indexPathForRowAtPoint(txtFieldPosition)
  if indexPath != nil {
     yourTablViewHere.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
  }
  return true
}
```

### Objective-C

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  CGPoint txtFieldPosition = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView: yourTablViewHere];
  NSLog(@"Begin txtFieldPosition : %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(txtFieldPosition));
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourTablViewHere indexPathForRowAtPoint:txtFieldPosition];

  if (indexPath != nil) {
     [yourTablViewHere scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am having issue get this to work on Swift. My UITextFields connected to UITableViewCell. If I implement this code inside my UIViewController I have no access to UITextFields. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have textfields in a table, the best way really is to resize the table - you need to set the tableView.frame to be smaller in height by the size of the keyboard (I think around 165 pixels) and then expand it again when the keyboard is dismissed.

You can optionally also disable user interaction for the tableView at that time as well, if you do not want the user scrolling.

Comment: I second this, and register for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification to find the size of the keyboard dynamically.

Comment: The number returned by the notification object doesn't work though.  Or at least it didn't in 2.2, the number returned was incorrect and I had to hard-code the 165 value to adjust the height correctly (it was off by five to ten pixels)

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly, and on iPad too.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{

    if(textField == textfield1){
            [accountName1TextField becomeFirstResponder];
        }else if(textField == textfield2){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            [textfield3 becomeFirstResponder];

        }else if(textField == textfield3){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            [textfield4 becomeFirstResponder];

        }else if(textField == textfield4){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            [textfield5 becomeFirstResponder];

        }else if(textField == textfield5){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            [textfield6 becomeFirstResponder];

        }else if(textField == textfield6){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            [textfield7 becomeFirstResponder];

        }else if(textField == textfield7){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            [textfield8 becomeFirstResponder];

        }else if(textField == textfield8){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            [textfield9 becomeFirstResponder];

        }else if(textField == textfield9){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
```

Comment: Why are you iffing and using special cases for each textfield?  ID each textfield from the cell's NSIndexPath and change that nasty if statement into 2 lines of code.  You really want a cellForRowAtIndexPath call and then get the textField from the cell.

Comment: Actually considering how incredibly flakey this situation is on iOS, I think it's OK to write "fully unwound, ridiculously literal" code for this situation.

Comment: Considering this answer was given over 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I tried almost the same approach and came up with a simpler and smaller code for the same.
I created a IBOutlet iTextView and associated with the UITextView in the IB.

```
 -(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        NSLog(@"Keyboard");
        CGRect keyFrame = [[[notification userInfo]objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]CGRectValue];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"resize view" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:1];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        CGRect frame = iTableView.frame;
        frame.size.height = frame.size.height -  keyFrame.size.height;
        iTableView.frame = frame;
        [iTableView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So after hours of grueling work trying to use these current solutions (and utterly failing) I finally got things working well, and updated them to use the new animation blocks. My answer is entirely based on [Ortwin's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-problem/4430737#4430737).

So for whatever reason the code above was just not working for me. My setup seemed fairly similar to others, but maybe because I was on an iPad or 4.3... no idea. It was doing some wacky math and shooting my tableview off the screen.

See end result of my solution: http://screencast.com/t/hjBCuRrPC  (Please ignore the photo. :-P)

So I went with the gist of what Ortwin was doing, but changed how it was doing some math to add up the origin.y & size.height of my table view with the height of the keyboard. When I subtract the height of the window from that result , it tells me how much intersection I have going on. If its greater than 0 (aka there is some overlap) I perform the animation of the frame height.

In addition there were some redraw issues that were solved by 1) Waiting to scroll to the cell until the animation was done and 2) using the UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState option when hiding the keyboard.

A couple things to note.

- _topmostRowBeforeKeyboardWasShown & _originalFrame are instance variables declared in the header.
- self.guestEntryTableView is my tableView (I'm in an external file)
- IASKCGRectSwap is Ortwin's method for flipping the coordinates of a frame
- I only update the height of the tableView if at least 50px of it is going to be showing
- Since I'm not in a UIViewController I don't have self.view, so I just return the tableView to its original frame

Again, I wouldn't have gotten near this answer if I Ortwin didn't provide the crux of it. Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = textField;

    if ([self.guestEntryTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows].count) {
        _topmostRowBeforeKeyboardWasShown = (NSIndexPath*)[[self.guestEntryTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        // this should never happen
        _topmostRowBeforeKeyboardWasShown = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = nil;
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    NSValue* keyboardFrameValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    // Reduce the tableView height by the part of the keyboard that actually covers the tableView
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGRect windowRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].bounds;
    CGRect viewRectAbsolute = [self.guestEntryTableView convertRect:self.guestEntryTableView.bounds toView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [keyboardFrameValue CGRectValue];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == orientation ||UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == orientation ) {
        windowRect = IASKCGRectSwap(windowRect);
        viewRectAbsolute = IASKCGRectSwap(viewRectAbsolute);
        keyboardFrame = IASKCGRectSwap(keyboardFrame);
    }

    // fix the coordinates of our rect to have a top left origin 0,0
    viewRectAbsolute = FixOriginRotation(viewRectAbsolute, orientation, windowRect.size.width, windowRect.size.height);

    CGRect frame = self.guestEntryTableView.frame;
    _originalFrame = self.guestEntryTableView.frame;

    int remainder = (viewRectAbsolute.origin.y + viewRectAbsolute.size.height + keyboardFrame.size.height) - windowRect.size.height;

    if (remainder > 0 && !(remainder > frame.size.height + 50)) {
        frame.size.height = frame.size.height - remainder;
        float duration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
        [UIView animateWithDuration: duration
                        animations:^{
                            self.guestEntryTableView.frame = frame;
                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            UITableViewCell *textFieldCell = (UITableViewCell*) [[self.activeTextField superview] superview];
                            NSIndexPath *textFieldIndexPath = [self.guestEntryTableView indexPathForCell:textFieldCell];
                            [self.guestEntryTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:textFieldIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
                        }];
    }

}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    float duration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    [UIView animateWithDuration: duration
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: (UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState)
                     animations:^{
                         self.guestEntryTableView.frame = _originalFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.guestEntryTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_topmostRowBeforeKeyboardWasShown atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
                     }];

}   

#pragma mark CGRect Utility function
CGRect IASKCGRectSwap(CGRect rect) {
    CGRect newRect;
    newRect.origin.x = rect.origin.y;
    newRect.origin.y = rect.origin.x;
    newRect.size.width = rect.size.height;
    newRect.size.height = rect.size.width;
    return newRect;
}

CGRect FixOriginRotation(CGRect rect, UIInterfaceOrientation orientation, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    CGRect newRect;
    switch(orientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            newRect = CGRectMake(parentWidth - (rect.size.width + rect.origin.x), rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            newRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, parentHeight - (rect.size.height + rect.origin.y), rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            newRect = rect;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            newRect = CGRectMake(parentWidth - (rect.size.width + rect.origin.x), parentHeight - (rect.size.height + rect.origin.y), rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
            break;
    }
    return newRect;
}
```

Comment: Added my FixOriginRotation function which fixes the coordinate system of the view before you update its frame etc. I think this is part of why I was having troubles at first. Wasn't aware the iOS Window Coordinate System Rotated with the device!

Answer (score 2):

This soluton works for me, PLEASE note the line

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height+160) animated:YES];
```

You can change the 160 value to match it work with you

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;
                        bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
     [activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
     [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height+160) animated:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   activeField = textField;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
     activeField = nil;
 }
// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;
    //bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting discussion thread, i also faced the same problem may be worse one because

1. I was using a custom cell and the textfield was inside that.
2. I had to use UIViewController to meet my requirements so cant take advantage of UITableViewController.
3. I had filter/ sort criterias in my table cell, ie ur cells keeps on changing and keeping track of the indexpath and all will not help.

So read the threads here and implemented my version, which helped me in pushing up my contents in iPad in **landscape** mode.
Here is code ( this is not fool proof and all, but it fixed my issue)
First u need to have a delegate in your custom cell class, which on editing begins, sends the textfield to ur viewcontroller and set the activefield = theTextField there

// IMPLEMENTED TO HANDLE LANDSCAPE MODE ONLY

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbValue = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect aRect = myTable.frame;

    CGSize kbSize = CGSizeMake(kbValue.height, kbValue.width);

    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height+50;
// This will the exact rect in which your textfield is present
        CGRect rect =  [myTable convertRect:activeField.bounds fromView:activeField];
// Scroll up only if required
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, rect.origin) ) {


            [myTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, rect.origin.y) animated:YES];

    }


}
```

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    myTable.contentInset = contentInsets;
    myTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbValue = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGSize kbSize = CGSizeMake(kbValue.height, kbValue.width);
    CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [myTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 10.0) animated:YES];
}
```

-anoop4real

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved such a problem by myself after I referred a mass of solutions found via Google and Stack Overflow.

First, please assure that you have set up an IBOutlet of your UIScrollView,
Then please take a close look at [Apple Doc: Keyboard Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html).
Finally, if you can scroll the background, but the keyboard still covers the Text Fields, please have a look at this piece of code:

```
// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your application might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

if (aRect.size.height < activeField.frame.origin.y+activeField.frame.size.height) {

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y+activeField.frame.size.height-aRect.size.height);

    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
```

The main difference between this piece and Apple's lies in the if condition. I believe apple's calculation of scroll distance and condition of whether text field covered by keyboard are not accurate, so I made my modification as above.

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 2):

An example in Swift, using the exact point of the text field from  [Get indexPath of UITextField in UITableViewCell with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073002/get-indexpath-of-uitextfield-in-uitableviewcell-with-swift):

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let pointInTable = textField.convertPoint(textField.bounds.origin, toView: self.accountsTableView)
    let textFieldIndexPath = self.accountsTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)
    accountsTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(textFieldIndexPath!, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Small variation with **Swift 4.2**...

On my UITableView I had many sections but I had to **avoid the floating header effect** so I used a "*dummyViewHeight*" approach as seen somewhere else here on Stack Overflow...
So this is my solution for this problem (it works also for keyboard + toolbar + suggestions):

Declare it as class constant:

```
let dummyViewHeight: CGFloat = 40.0
```

Then

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //... some stuff here, not needed for this example

    // Create non floating header
    tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: dummyViewHeight))
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -dummyViewHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    addObservers()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    removeObservers()
}
```

And here all the magic...

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size.height
        tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width, height: dummyViewHeight))
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -dummyViewHeight, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width, height: self.dummyViewHeight))
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -self.dummyViewHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewController` does the Scrolling automatically, indeed.
The difference compared to using a `UIViewController` is, that you have to create Navbar-Buttonitems programmatically by using the `NavigationController`, when using a `TableViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Another easy method (only works with one section)

```
//cellForRowAtIndexPath
UItextField *tf;
[cell addSubview:tf];
tf.tag = indexPath.row;
tf.delegate = self;

//textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)text
[[self.tableView scrollToRowsAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:text.tag in section:SECTIONINTEGER] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your UITableView is managed by a subclass of UITableViewController and not UITableView, and the text field delegate is the UITableViewController, it should manage all the scrolling automatically -- all these other comments are very difficult to implement in practice.

For a good example see the apple example code project: TaggedLocations.

You can see that it scrolls automatically, but there doesn't seem to be any code that does this.  This project also has custom table view cells, so if you build your application with it as a guide, you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I made this work, which is a mixture of Sam Ho and Marcel W's answers, and some of my own bug fixes made to my crappy code.  I was using a UITableViewController.  The table now resizes correctly when the keyboard is shown.

1) In `viewDidLoad` I added:

`self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

2) I had forgotten to call the `super` equivalents in `viewWillAppear` and `awakeFromNib`.  I added these back in.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and fast solution.

I just scroll to the right cell whenever scrolling happens

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Assuming I know table now is in this mode "_keepMyCellOnTop"
& I know selected cell "_selectedCellIndex" or scroll to selected cell

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{

    if (_keepMyCellOnTop)
    {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_selectedCellIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    }
}
```

This will prevent scrolling.

Placing the code in `-(void) scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`
 will result a scroll up and down

Answer (score 1):

I will throw my solution (Or QuickDialog's that is) into the hat. Basically wait to animate to the scrolling. It would be nice to get the keyboard animation JIT instead of the magic number.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.emailTextField) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 50 * USEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this often in my projects. This solution works with scrollviews, tableviews or collectionviews and it’s easy to setup.
It also automatically hooks up “Next” buttons on the keyboard to switch through the text fields.

Check it [here](http://icodetricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/uitextfields-and-keyboard-issues/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using these and they work like a charm:

BSKeyboardControls - [BSKeyboardControls github](https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls)

TPKeyboardAvoiding - [TPKeyboardAvoiding github](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 1):

in viewdidload

```
-(void)viewdidload{

[super viewdidload];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
}

    -(void)keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification*)sender{

        NSLog(@"keyboardwillchange sender %@",sender);

float margin=0  // set your own topmargin


        CGFloat originY = [[sender.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].origin.y;


        if (originY >= self.view.frame.size.height){

            NSLog(@"keyboardclose");



            [tb_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, margin, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-margin)];

        }else{

            NSLog(@"keyobard on");

            float adjustedHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - margin - (self.view.frame.size.height-originY);

            [tb_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, margin, self.view.frame.size.width, adjustedHeight)];
        }







    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No Need Any Calculations, Use below code it will work:
This code I used in my Customised UITableviewcell, It's working:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)}


func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {

if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
}}


func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {

if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked again into the iOS 5.0 lib reference and found this section titled "Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard": [TextAndWebiPhoneOS KeyboardManagement](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Is this new since iOS 5, perhaps? I haven't read into it yet as I'm in the middle of something else, but perhaps others know more and can enlighten me and others here.

Does the Apple doc supersede what's been discussed here or is the information here still useful to iOS 5 SDK users?

Comment: As someone mentioned above, this Doc said: Note: This chapter contains information that used to be in iPhone Application Programming Guide. The information in this chapter has not been updated specifically for iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no "right" way to do this. You have to choose the best fit solution for your use case. 
In my iPad App I have a `UIViewController` that is presented modal as `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` and consists of an `UITableView`. This table contains two `UITextFields` per cell. 
Just calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method doesn't work for me. Therefore I have created a `tableFooterView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    m_footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, m_tableView.frame.size.width, 300.0f)];
    [m_footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [m_tableView setTableFooterView:m_footerView];
    [m_footerView release];
}
```

The idea is that keyboard hides the `tableFooterView` and not the `UITextFields`. So the `tableFooterView` must be high enough. After that you can use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method.

I think it's also possible to show and hide the `tableFooterView` dynamically by adding the observers for the keyboard notifications but I haven't tried it yet:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
     [m_tableView setTableFooterView:m_footerView];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
     [m_tableView setTableFooterView:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is through UITableViewController.

**If you want a UITableView in a UIViewController**, just make a ContentView with an embedded UITableViewController and put the following lines in the viedDidLoad of the UIViewController:

```
self.tableView = ((UITableViewController*)self.childViewControllers[0]).tableView;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution inspired by "Event edit" screen from iOS7 Calendar app.

One of key points of this solution is that keyboard is dismissed when user scrolls table.

Implementation:

1) Add property that will store selected textfield:

```
@property (strong) UITextField *currentTextField;
```

and BOOL variable that we will use to check if we need to hide keyboard when user scrolls table.

```
BOOL hideKeyboardOnScroll;
```

2) Handle UITextField delegate callbacks:

```
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *) textField {
    self.currentTextField = textField;
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField *) textField {
    self.currentTextField = nil;
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];

    CGPoint newContentOffset = CGPointZero;
    if (tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.size.height) {
        newContentOffset.y = MIN(tableView.contentOffset.y, tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height);
    }
    [tableView setContentOffset: newContentOffset animated: YES];

    return YES;
}
```

3) Handle UIScrollViewDelegate method to check that user scroll view.

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) scrollView {
    if (hideKeyboardOnScroll == YES) {
        [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

4) Subscribe to keyboard notifications in viewcontroller's [viewWillAppear] method and unsubscribe in [viewWillDisappear] method.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    [ [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                  name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object: nil];
    [ [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                  name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object: nil];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];

    [ [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object: nil];
    [ [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object: nil];    
}
```

5) Handle keyboard notifications:

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification *) notification {
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [ [ [notification userInfo] objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    // Find cell with textfield.
    CGRect textFieldFrame = [tableView convertRect: self.currentTextField.frame fromView: self.currentTextField];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: textFieldFrame.origin];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    //

    // Shrink tableView size.
    CGRect tableViewFrame = tableView.frame;
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width,
                             self.view.frame.size.height - tableView.frame.origin.y - keyboardFrame.size.height);
    //

    // Check if cell is visible in shrinked table size.
    BOOL cellIsFullyVisible = YES;
    if ( cell.frame.origin.y < tableView.contentOffset.y ||
        (cell.frame.origin.y + cell.frame.size.height) > (tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.frame.size.height) ) {
        cellIsFullyVisible = NO;
    }
    //

    // If cell is not fully visible when scroll table to show cell;
    if (cellIsFullyVisible == NO) {
        CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointMake(tableView.contentOffset.x, CGRectGetMaxY(cell.frame) - tableView.frame.size.height);
        if (cell.frame.origin.y < tableView.contentOffset.y) {
            contentOffset.y = cell.frame.origin.y;
        }
        contentOffset.y = MAX(0, contentOffset.y);

        // For some reason [setContentOffset] is called without delay then
        // this code may not work for some cells. That why we call it with brief delay.
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{
                [tableView setContentOffset: contentOffset animated: NO];
            } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                hideKeyboardOnScroll = YES;
            }];
        });
    } else {
        hideKeyboardOnScroll = YES;
    }
    //

    // Finally restore original table frame.
    tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
    //
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide: (NSNotification *) notification {
    [super keyboardWillHide: notification];

    hideKeyboardOnScroll = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at my version :)

```
    - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = cellSelected.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [cellSelected.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, cellSelected.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
}


- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// scroll tableview so content ends at the middle of the tableview (out of the way of the keyboard)
CGPoint newContentOffset = CGPointMake(0, [self.tableView contentSize].height - (self.tableView.bounds.size.height / 2));
[self.tableView setContentOffset:newContentOffset animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Swift 3-4 with animations and keyboard frame changing:**

First, create a Bool:

```
// MARK: - Private Properties
private var isKeyboardShowing = false
```

Secondly, add Observers to the System Keyboard Notifications:

```
// MARK: - Overriding ViewController Life Cycle Methods
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame), name: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
}
```

Thirdly, prepare the animation function:

```
func adjustTableViewInsets(keyboardHeight: CGFloat, duration: NSNumber, curve: NSNumber){
    var extraHeight: CGFloat = 0
    if keyboardHeight > 0 {
        extraHeight = 20
        isKeyboardShowing = true
    } else {
        isKeyboardShowing = false
    }

    let contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight + extraHeight, right: 0)
    func animateFunc() {
        //refresh constraints
        //self.view.layoutSubviews()
        tableView.contentInset = contentInset
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve))], animations: animateFunc, completion: nil)
}
```

Then add the target/action methods (called by the observers):

```
// MARK: - Target/Selector Actions
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if !isKeyboardShowing {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height

            let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber
            let curve = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber

            adjustTableViewInsets(keyboardHeight: keyboardHeight, duration: duration, curve: curve)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber
    let curve = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber
    adjustTableViewInsets(keyboardHeight: 0, duration: duration, curve: curve)
}

func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification: NSNotification) {
    if isKeyboardShowing {
        let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber
        let curve = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber

        if let newKeyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let keyboardHeight = newKeyboardSize.height
            adjustTableViewInsets(keyboardHeight: keyboardHeight, duration: duration, curve: curve)
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, don't forget to remove observers in deinit or in viewWillDisappear:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered another bug when using UITableViewController. It wasn't scrolling automatically when keyboard showed up. I noticed that it was because of contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never on UITableView.