# UITableView can not scroll down. Keyboard is shown and not shown at the same time

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uitextview

I have a `UITableView` and its `UITableViewCell`s can independently change their sizes via the function `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`. They store `UIImage`s of varying sizes. When I tap an image the keyboard is shown (lets say it is for tagging the images).

When I have, lets say, 3 cells (images) with a total height of 1 pixel *less* than the screen size it is all good. The keyboard is shown and I can scroll to see all the cells (images).

But when I add one more, pushing the total size to be more than the screen, it all breaks. The keyboard seems to be shown (I have an extra button on top, making it some pixels higher than the original keyboard, that is shown). But I cannot write anything. The button on top of the keyboard is to resign the keyboard, and it does not work. It is kind of stuck.

The project can be downloaded here:https://github.com/TokyoBirdy/cecilia/tree/master/Test (excuse the messy code)

Comment: Take a look at these two and see if any of them will help your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842560/uitableview-wont-scroll-after-editing-view-frame-and-origin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem of the locked scrolling by removing the code that edits the view's origin. In addition, I implemented scrolling to the bottom cell by using the tableview's contentSize property in my calculations.

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{

  if(!isKeyboardShowing)
    {
    isKeyboardShowing = YES;
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = keyboardBounds.size.height;

            CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
            frame.size.height += keyboardHeight;
            self.view.frame = frame;

    CGPoint scrollPoint = frame.origin;
    scrollPoint.y += _tableView.contentSize.height - keyboardHeight;
    [_tableView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```