# iPhone: Having trouble figuring out how to scroll a UITableView with custom UITextField cells automatically when entering text

Tags: iphone, uitableview, keyboard, scroll, uitextfield

Ok, I know this seems like a duplicate question, but don't think it is. I actually have this implemented already (thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-problem)), but it seems sluggish. I am willing to tweak it a bit, but I ran across a demo app by [AboutObjects](http://www.aboutobjects.com) that seems to have exactly the right functionality with absolutely no code doing it. I have looked through their demo code dozens of times, and I can't figure out what they are doing that I am not. The code to look at is in their [iPhone Development Tutorials](http://www.aboutobjects.com/iphone_development/tutorials.html) section, and is called "Editable TableView" (2nd from the bottom). There are a couple of questions on the forums on that site asking how they got the functionality, but there is no answer (other than "It's a built in function"). Does anyone have any clue as to why their UITableView would implement the input scrolling by default (including being able to scroll the view manually when the keyboard pops up, which I cannot get to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what I was doing wrong, or what I changed, but it "just works" now. No code necessary. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the UITableViewController handles the automatic scrolling including scrolling up making rows visible when the keyboard pops up.