# how to scroll table on the click event of some cell in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am right now working with one application where i need to take one uitableview with uilable and textfield in each cell.I am able to scroll the table manually once the user starts writing, but what i want is that when i click on the textfield,the table should scroll upward so that the user is able to see what he has entered in the textfield.Same thing i saw once i logged in the iphone facebook.

this is the code for manually scrolling the table :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 250;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGRect viewRect    = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160);
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    return footerView;
}
```

Is there any way around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-problem/672003#672003) describes what you want to achieve.
Also see this [tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html) which nicely describes how to solve this problem.

Happy coding & happy new year

Comment: Thank you so much for the great help..Happy new year to u too :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, table view should scroll up when keyboard appears automatically (when text field is placed on table view, and when table is controlled by tableViewController).

Comment: Well,the keypad appears but it is not scrolling up automatically and as a result,it hides half of the part of the uitableview. Any solution??