# UITableView.ScrollRectToVisible() doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: uitableview, scroll, xamarin.ios

I have a table view containing a variable amount of sections and custom cells. On some occasions, a cell may resize within RowSelected(). Whenever that happens, I'd like to also make sure the cell is completely visible after resizing (enlarging) it.

I have that working in another table that just modifies the underlying data so that the table view source will provide a larger cell. I then reload the cell and scroll it visible like so:

```
// Modify data
//...

// Reload cell
tableView.ReloadRows(new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
tableView.ScrollRectToVisible(tableView.CellAt(indexPath).Frame, true);
```

The problem arises in a table view where resizing may not only be triggered by RowSelected(), but also by events on UI elements within the cells.

The events then call a method to reload the cell:

```
void updateCell() {
  if (cell.Superview != null) {
    UITableView tableView = (UITableView)cell.Superview;
    tableView.ReloadRows(new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);

    // Get the new (possibly enlarged) frame
    RectangleF frame = tableView.CellAt(indexPath).Frame;
    Console.WriteLine("This really is the new large frame, height: {0}", frame.Height);

    // Try to scroll it visible
    tableView.ScrollRectToVisible(frame, true);
  }
}
```

This scrolls fine for all cells but the bottom-most. It only makes the old frame of that cell visible. I double-checked that it really provides the new cell frame to ScrollRectToVisible().

So it seems ScrollRectToVisible() is bound to the old content size of the table - even after reloading rows. I tried to work around that by providing a new content size with the calculated difference in height. That does work but feels really hackish to me.

Is there some cleaner way to do things?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-problem

Comment: Can you please share your code ?I am looking to show only 3 cells whenever user scrolls the talbe, & if the scrolling ends in between, intstead of showing cutting cells , I would like to show complete cells, checking nearby cells index.Any suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead using this:

```
tableView.ScrollRectToVisible(_: animated: )
```

Use it to scroll **UITableView** to bottom row:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: at: animated: )
```