# Let tableview's last cell scroll to half way up the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with custom cells. Each cell has a UITextfield. When the last cell's textfield is clicked, the keyboard pops up and covers it and the table view won't scroll up any further. Is there a property of UITableview that can be set so that the last cell can scroll to half way up the screen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a two ways to approach this (that I can think about off the top of my head):

- You can use the `tableFooterView` property of `UITableView` to set an arbitrary, empty view to be about half the size of your table.
- You can add empty cells to the bottom of your table

Both of these approaches will accomplish roughly the same thing, but using the `tableFooterView` property is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

see [Making a UITableView scroll when text field is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-problem) for a list of solution..

Also basing your view controller from UITableViewController (since you say its a table) will provide all this functionality automatically!