# How do I scroll the UIScrollView when the keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, scrollview

I'm having trouble with my code. I'm trying to move the `UIScrollView` when I'm editing an `UITextField` that should be hidden by the keyboard pop.

I'm moving the main frame right now because I don't know how to 'scroll up' in the code.
So, I did a little bit of code, it's working fine but when I edit an UItextfield and I switch to another `UITextField` without pressing on the 'return' button the main view goes waaayyyyy to far up.

I did an `NSLog()` with my variables size, distance and textFieldRect.origin.y as you can see below. When I put two `UITextField` at the same place (y origin) and I do this particular 'switch' (wihtout pressing return) , I get the same numbers, whereas my code worked fine for the first `UITextField` editing but not for the second editing.

Check this out:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
{
    int size;
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    size = textFieldRect.origin.y + textFieldRect.size.height;
    if (change == FALSE)
    {
        size = size - distance;
    }
    if (size < PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT)
    {
        distance = 0;
    }
    else if (size > PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT)
    {
        distance = size - PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT + 5; // +5 px for more visibility
    }
    NSLog(@"origin %f", textFieldRect.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"size %d", size);
    NSLog(@"distance %d", distance);
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= distance;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    change = FALSE;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    change = TRUE;
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += distance;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

The recommended way from Apple is to change the `contentInset` of the `UIScrollView`. It is a very elegant solution, because you do not have to mess with the `contentSize`. 
Following code is copied from the [Keyboard Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), where the handling of this issue is explained. You should have a look into it.

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent    
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

**Swift version:**

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onKeyboardAppear(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onKeyboardDisappear(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
}

// Don't forget to unregister when done
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func onKeyboardAppear(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let rect: CGRect = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    let kbSize = rect.size

    let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kbSize.height, 0)
    scrollView.contentInset = insets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    var aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

    let activeField: UITextField? = [addressTextView, servicePathTextView, usernameTextView, passwordTextView].first { $0.isFirstResponder }
    if let activeField = activeField {
        if !aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin) {
            let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height)
            scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

@objc func onKeyboardDisappear(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very usefull! I have a last problem, I have on the top a toolbar that is 44px heigh.What do I have to change in the code above to make it work if the scrollview origin is 44px ?

Comment: It should not matter where the scrollView is originated. The code just "pushes" the scrollView up depending on the keyboard size. So the origin/size of the scrollView shouldn't be relevant. I just created a project and set the origin.y of the scrollView to 44. It still worked. You can check whether it works or not by scrolling to the bottom and look at the scrollbar on the right. If you have bounces on, you can see that the scrollbar gets very small just on top of the keyboard, which is correct. If you see the scrollbar vanishing behind the keyboard, then something is wrong. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sry, I did not get that you were talking about the scrolling part. Yes, the activeField is just a placeholder for your UITextField property. So substitute it and try again. You do not need to change the size, or else the textField will really get bigger in height.

Comment: So that people know, the code Apple provided shown here by iMasa is pretty much drop-in code. All you have to do is add the textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing methods in addition to what iMasa has. Then, @synthesize a variable named activeField that's the same kind as scrollView (you may have named this differently). You might have to create this in .h file as well before you @ synthesize. Finally, call the registerForKeyboardNotifications somewhere like ViewDidLoad method (like this: [self registerForKeyboardNotifications]).

Comment: You actually do not want to overwrite the existing contentInsets.top, this if you do your view may slide up behind Navigation.

Comment: @isoyaboy Just look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2630476/849484) solution,works perfect for all versions :)

Comment: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding   This is super simple solution

Comment: It's good to convert `activeField.frame` to relative frame as `activeField` doesn't have to be an immediate child to `self.view`. Updated code should look something like:

`CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
CGRect relativeFieldFrame = [activeField convertRect:activeField.frame toView:self.view];
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, relativeFieldFrame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, relativeFieldFrame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
    [self.mainView.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}`

Comment: I wrap everything in one class. Just call some lines of code when your viewcontroller is loaded.
Please have a look to sample code project: https://github.com/caohuuloc/KeyboardInsetScrollView

Comment: Why are you using ```NSNotificationCenter```? Can't you just connect the text field to the delegate and that will then automatically call the appropriate text field methods for you??

Comment: Does anyone ever get a delay when the textfield is clicked and the keyboard shows up then the scrollview scrolls? Theres a delay before the scrollview scrolls as opposed to it happening immediately. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Better use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` than `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` to prevent delay.

Comment: I had to use the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` key on iOS 11 because the `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` would often give me a height of zero.

Comment: In swift verion, if !aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin) { then scroll to right position }. The NOT condition is missing.

Comment: Thanks. This works great once you change a few values to suit Swift 5. But I really question why Apple didn't build this behaviour in by default since it is such a common need. Compare this to Android where you never need to worry about such keyboard issues since the OS takes care of it automatically.

Answer (score 71):

I just implemented this with Swift 2.0 for iOS9 on Xcode 7 (beta 6), works fine here.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    registerKeyboardNotifications()
}

func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue.size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var viewRect = view.frame
    viewRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    if CGRectContainsPoint(viewRect, textField.frame.origin) {
        let scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

**Edited for Swift 3**

Seems like you only need to set the `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInset` with Swift 3, the scrolling/contentOffset is done automatically..

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    registerKeyboardNotifications()
}

func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                         selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
                                         name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
                                         object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                         selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
                                         name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                         object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardInfo = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardInfo.cgRectValue.size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    scrollView.contentInset = .zero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your code please? I have two text field and once I edit the first one it scroll down while the the second textField scroll up.

Comment: On iPad this moves the scroll view down instead of up. Any idea what's happening there?

Comment: @can the textField referred to is a variable you set for your viewcontroller based on the current first responder

Comment: I wonder why Apple took in upon themselves to scroll the active text field above the keyboard for us now.

Comment: This worked when I changed it to only modify `scrollView.contentInset.bottom` because the top content inset was preventing the content from going under the navigation bar and this answer sets that to zero.

Comment: in swift 4 put @objc on keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide methods

Comment: Is `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver` better to be done in `viewWillDisappear`?, to pair with `viewWillAppear` ?

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 5** Solution:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    registerKeyboardNotifications()
}

func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                         selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
                                         name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                         object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                         selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
                                         name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                         object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardInfo = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardInfo.cgRectValue.size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    scrollView.contentInset = .zero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
}
```

Comment: worked mostly, just needed to change `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

Comment: I apply this code in UITableView. But TableView is not scrolling up immediately.

Comment: `UIKeyboardWillShow`, `UIKeyboardWillHide`, and  `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` have been renamed to `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification`, and `UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`.

Answer (score 16):

All the answers here seem to forget about landscape possibilities. If you would like this to work when the device is rotated to a landscape view, then you will face problems.

The trick here is that although the view is aware of the orientation, the keyboard is not. This means in Landscape, the keyboards width is actually its height and visa versa.

To modify Apples recommended way of changing the content insets and get it support landscape orientation, I would recommend using the following:

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notif userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {
        CGSize origKeySize = keyboardSize;
        keyboardSize.height = origKeySize.width;
        keyboardSize.width = origKeySize.height;
    }
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0);
    scroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect rect = scroller.frame;
    rect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    NSLog(@"Rect Size Height: %f", rect.size.height);

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(rect, activeField.frame.origin)) {
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, activeField.frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height);
        NSLog(@"Point Height: %f", point.y);
        [scroller setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent    
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

---

The part to pay attention to here is the following:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notif userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {
    CGSize origKeySize = keyboardSize;
    keyboardSize.height = origKeySize.width;
    keyboardSize.width = origKeySize.height;
}
```

What is does, is detects what orientation the device is in. If it is landscape, it will 'swap' the width and height values of the keyboardSize variable to ensure that the correct values are being used in each orientation.

Comment: well, you might want to do extra adjustment (reduction) of the content inset bottom per this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704513/ios-scrollview-not-scrolling-to-correct-position-when-keyboard-visible in case the scroller is occupying the whole height of the screen UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height - ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - cvf.origin.y - cvf.size.height), 0.0); where cvf is the scroller.frame

Comment: if (orientation == **UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft** || orientation == **UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight**)

Answer (score 9):

For this stuff no need to lot's of coding it's very easy like below code:-

your all textfiled in UIScrollview from nib like this image:-

[image]

`YourViewController.h`

```
@interface cntrInquiryViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
{
     IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
     IBOutlet UITextField *txtEmail;
     IBOutlet UIScrollView *srcScrollView;
}
@end
```

**connect IBOutlet from nib and also Connect each delegate of UItextfiled and scrollview delegate from NIB**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    srcScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(FMTextField *)textField
{
    [srcScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,textField.center.y-140) animated:YES];//you can set your  y cordinate as your req also
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     [srcScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];


    return YES;
}
```

**NOTE** if Text-filed delegate not connected then no one method working please insure that all iBOulate and delegate connected correctly

Comment: This is a very old approach and should not be used. It relies on harcoded values and assumptions that are no longer relevant.

Comment: @Womble There are many answers which are old but relevant to the question at that time (When the question was asked). So, Don't down-vote without the reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Apple's recommendation recoded in **Swift** + Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS (basing on these following links: [link 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7), [link 2](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/), [link 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Isu3xLjjyZg)):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var t1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var t2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var t3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var t4: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var srcScrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    var contentViewCoordinates: CGPoint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        /* Constraints on content view */
        let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.contentView,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem:self.view,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Left,
            multiplier:1.0,
            constant:0)
        self.view.addConstraint(leftConstraint)

        let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.contentView,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem:self.view,
            attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Right,
            multiplier:1.0,
            constant:0)
        self.view.addConstraint(rightConstraint)

        /* Tap gesture */
        let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideKeyboard")
        // prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        srcScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        /* Save content view coordinates */
        contentViewCoordinates = contentView.frame.origin
    }

    func hideKeyboard() {
        t1.resignFirstResponder()
        t2.resignFirstResponder()
        t3.resignFirstResponder()
        t4.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    var activeField: UITextField?

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = nil
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardOnScreen:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardOffScreen:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardOnScreen(notification: NSNotification){
        // Retrieve the size and top margin (inset is the fancy word used by Apple) 
        // of the keyboard displayed.
        let info: NSDictionary  = notification.userInfo!
        let kbSize = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue().size
        let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets  = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize!.height, 0.0)

        srcScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        srcScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= kbSize!.height
        //you may not need to scroll, see if the active field is already visible
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin) == false) {
            let scrollPoint:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField!.frame.origin.y - kbSize!.height)
            srcScrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
        }
    }

//    func keyboardOnScreen(aNotification: NSNotification) {
//        let info: NSDictionary  = aNotification.userInfo!
//        let kbSize = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue().size
//        
//        var bkgndRect: CGRect! = activeField?.superview?.frame
//        
//        bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize!.height
//        
//        activeField?.superview?.frame = bkgndRect
//        
//        srcScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0.0, activeField!.frame.origin.y - kbSize!.height), animated: true)
//    }

    func keyboardOffScreen(notification: NSNotification){
        let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

        srcScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        srcScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        self.srcScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -self.view.frame.origin.y/2), animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: After one day of hard work I managed to implement the apple's recommendation in Swift + modified their code a little bit + adjusted it making it responsive on all apples devices, so before down voting, please tell me why. None of the code above works correctly on all devices and all layout situations. However mine does work on all apple devices and layout situations.

Comment: I suppose you also need to unsubscribe from the notification center before the view dies ?

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4.2** solution that takes possible heights of UIToolbar and UITabBar into account.

```
private func setupKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIControl.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIControl.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size

    let tabbarHeight = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height ?? 0
    let toolbarHeight = navigationController?.toolbar.frame.size.height ?? 0
    let bottomInset = keyboardSize.height - tabbarHeight - toolbarHeight

    scrollView.contentInset.bottom = bottomInset
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = bottomInset
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    scrollView.contentInset = .zero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
}
```

And, if you're targeting < iOS 9, you have to unregister the observer at some point (thanks [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161666/how-do-i-scroll-the-uiscrollview-when-the-keyboard-appears/52195756#comment95350281_52195756))

Comment: Does it take into account space under tabbar on iPhone X? It is where iOS stripe appears.

Comment: iOS9+ you don't need to remove the observer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I would update in Apple code is the keyboardWillBeHidden: method, to provide smooth transition.

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    }];
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a **Swift 3** compatible answer, that will also work with view controllers within a navigation controller - as they will change the scroll views `contentInset.top` property.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.registerKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.unregisterKeyboardNotifications()
}

func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func unregisterKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}


func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardInfo = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardInfo.cgRectValue.size

    // Get the existing contentInset for the scrollView and set the bottom property to be the height of the keyboard
    var contentInset = self.scrollView.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardSize.height

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    var contentInset = self.scrollView.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = 0

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the final code with improvements in **Swift**

```
    //MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method
    self.textField = textField
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

//MARK: Keyboard handling
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unregisterKeyboardNotifications()
}

func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(UCProfileSettingsViewController.keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(UCProfileSettingsViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func unregisterKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue.size
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var viewRect = self.view.frame
    viewRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    let relativeFieldFrame: CGRect = textField.convertRect(textField.frame, toView: self.view)
    if CGRectContainsPoint(viewRect, relativeFieldFrame.origin) {
        let scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, relativeFieldFrame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Comment: I think your logic is reversed - you only want to scroll if CGRectContainsPoint does NOT contain the relativeFieldFrame.origin.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the above answers have been outdated. Also not perfect when scroll.

Here's a swift version.

It will scroll right below the textField, no spare space. And It will restore to the way it was like its first appear.

```
//add observer
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ARVHttpPlayVC.keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ARVHttpPlayVC.keyboardDidHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue.size
    let difference = keyboardSize.height - (self.view.frame.height - inputTextField.frame.origin.y - inputTextField.frame.size.height)
    if difference > 0 {
        var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
        contentInset.bottom = difference
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset

        let scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, difference)
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
    }

}

func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}

//remove observer
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: It does scrollup a bit, but not enough to expose the whole height. I'm using Swift 2.3 and testing it on iphone 5.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've been using. It's simple and it works well.

```
#pragma mark - Scrolling

-(void)scrollElement:(UIView *)view toPoint:(float)y
{
    CGRect theFrame = view.frame;
    float orig_y = theFrame.origin.y;
    float diff = y - orig_y;

    if (diff < 0) 
        [self scrollToY:diff];

    else 
        [self scrollToY:0];
}

-(void)scrollToY:(float)y
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, y);
    }];
}
```

Use the `UITextField` delegate call `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` to shift your view upwards, and also add a notification observer to return the view to normal when the keyboard hides:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    if (self.view.frame.origin.y == 0)
        [self scrollToY:-90.0];  // y can be changed to your liking

}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)note
{
    [self scrollToY:0];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest solutions is using the following protocol:

```
protocol ScrollViewKeyboardDelegate: class {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView? { get set }

    func registerKeyboardNotifications()
    func unregisterKeyboardNotifications()
}

extension ScrollViewKeyboardDelegate where Self: UIViewController {
    func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
            object: nil,
            queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
                self?.keyboardWillBeShown(notification)
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil,
            queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
                self?.keyboardWillBeHidden(notification)
        }
    }

    func unregisterKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(
            self,
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(
            self,
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }

    func keyboardWillBeShown(_ notification: Notification) {
        let info = notification.userInfo
        let key = (info?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)
        let aKeyboardSize = key?.cgRectValue

        guard let keyboardSize = aKeyboardSize,
            let scrollView = self.scrollView else {
                return
        }

        let bottomInset = keyboardSize.height
        scrollView.contentInset.bottom = bottomInset
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = bottomInset
        if let activeField = self.view.firstResponder {
            let yPosition = activeField.frame.origin.y - bottomInset
            if yPosition > 0 {
                let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: yPosition)
                scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.scrollView?.contentInset = .zero
        self.scrollView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var firstResponder: UIView? {
        guard !isFirstResponder else { return self }
        return subviews.first(where: {$0.firstResponder != nil })
    }
}
```

When you want to use this protocol, you only need to conform to it and assign your scroll view in your controller as follows:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet var scrollViewOutlet: UIScrollView?
      var scrollView: UIScrollView?

      public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView = self.scrollViewOutlet
        self.scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.registerKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    extension MyViewController: ScrollViewKeyboardDelegate {}

    deinit {
       self.unregisterKeyboardNotifications()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that like this. It's a lot of code but it ensures, that the textField currently in focus is is vertically centered in the 'available space':

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue *keyBoardEndFrame = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [keyBoardEndFrame CGRectValue].size;
    self.keyboardSize = keyboardSize;

    [self adjustScrollViewOffsetToCenterTextField:self.currentTextField];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.keyboardSize = CGSizeZero;
}

- (IBAction)textFieldGotFocus:(UITextField *)sender {
    sender.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardAccessoryView;
    self.currentTextField = sender;
    [self adjustScrollViewOffsetToCenterTextField:sender];    
}

- (void)adjustScrollViewOffsetToCenterTextField:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect textFieldFrame = textField.frame;
    float keyboardHeight = MIN(self.keyboardSize.width, self.keyboardSize.height);

    float visibleScrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.size.height - keyboardHeight;
    float offsetInScrollViewCoords = (visibleScrollViewHeight / 2) - (textFieldFrame.size.height / 2);

    float scrollViewOffset = textFieldFrame.origin.y - offsetInScrollViewCoords;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollViewOffset);
    }completion:NULL];

}

you'll need these two properties in your @interface...
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize keyboardSize;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *currentTextField;
```

Note that the `- (IBAction)textFieldGotFocus:` action is hooked up to the every textField's `DidBeginEditing` state.

Also it would be a little better to get the animation duration from the keyboard notification and use that for the scrollview animation instead of a fixed value, but sue me, this was good enough for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use following extension if you don't want to calculate too much:

```
func scrollSubviewToBeVisible(subview: UIView, animated: Bool) {
    let visibleFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, self.contentInset)
    let subviewFrame = subview.convertRect(subview.bounds, toView: self)
    if (!CGRectContainsRect(visibleFrame, subviewFrame)) {
        self.scrollRectToVisible(subviewFrame, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

And maybe you want keep your UITextField always visible:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    self.scrollView?.scrollSubviewToBeVisible(textView, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setupViewResizerOnKeyboardShown()
}

func setupViewResizerOnKeyboardShown() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShowForResizing),
                                           name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
                                           object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHideForResizing),
                                           name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                           object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShowForResizing(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
        let window = self.view.window?.frame {
        // We're not just minusing the kb height from the view height because
        // the view could already have been resized for the keyboard before
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                 y: self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                 width: self.view.frame.width,
                                 height: window.origin.y + window.height - keyboardSize.height)

    } else {
        debugPrint("We're showing the keyboard and either the keyboard size or window is nil: panic widely.")
    }
}

func keyboardWillHideForResizing(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                 y: self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                 width: self.view.frame.width,
                                 height: viewHeight) //viewHeight + keyboardSize.height

    } else {
        debugPrint("We're about to hide the keyboard and the keyboard size is nil. Now is the rapture.")
    }
}

deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5** solution based on [Masa solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163543/1656515) above - changes in relation to it:

- using `keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of
  `keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`, because
  `keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` can on first show return other value
  as described for example here: [keyboard height varies when appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358783/keyboard-height-varies-when-appearing)
- using "will" instead of "did" notifications plus changing it to Swift 5 keys names: `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification`/`UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification` instead of `NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow`/`NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide`

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onKeyboardAppear(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onKeyboardDisappear(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func onKeyboardAppear(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let info = notification.userInfo, let kbSize = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size else { return }

    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: kbSize.height, right: 0)

    scrollView.contentInset = insets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets

    //Other changes if needed
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: The func `onKeyboardDisappear` is missing in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    self.stackView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: height, right: 0)
    self.stackView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.stackView.contentInset
    self.stackView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition , width: Int(self.view.bounds.width), height: 80), animated: true)
```

height - keyboard height

y position - cursor position

height: 80 - From keyboard top where cursor should be.
Add keyboard notification in view did load, If keyboard is present call this function with keyboard height and cursor height. I'm using it for richEditorTextView in scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll by using the property `contentOffset` in `UIScrollView`, e.g.,

```
CGPoint offset = scrollview.contentOffset;
offset.y -= KEYBOARD_HEIGHT + 5;
scrollview.contentOffset = offset;
```

There's also a method to do animated scrolling.

As for the reason why your second edit is not scrolling correctly, it could be because you seem to assume that a new keyboard will appear every time editing starts. You could try checking if you've already adjusted for the "keyboard" visible position (and likewise check for keyboard visibility at the moment before reverting it).

A better solution might be to listen for the keyboard notification, e.g.:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a UIScrollView to do this. I used this code and it works for me:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

   if (textField==_myTextField)
   {
      [self keyBoardAppeared];
   }
   return true;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   if (textField==_myTextField)
   {
      [self keyBoardDisappeared];
   }
}

-(void) keyBoardAppeared
{
   CGRect frame = self.view.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y-215, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
}

-(void) keyBoardDisappeared
{
   CGRect frame = self.view.frame;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y+215, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
}
```

Comment: Problems: Uses hard-coded values. Shifts your whole UI up and down which will often mess up the looks of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question now but i thought it might help others. I wanted something a little easier to implement for a few apps i had, so i made a class for this. You can download it here if you want: https://github.com/sdernley/iOSTextFieldHandler

It's as simple as setting all of the UITextFields to have a delegate of self

```
textfieldname.delegate = self;
```

And then adding this to your view controller with the name of your scrollView and submit button

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [iOSTextFieldHandler TextboxKeyboardMover:containingScrollView tf:textField btn:btnSubmit];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is my solutions which works ( 5 steps )

Step1: Add an observer to catch which UITEXTFIELD or UITEXTVIEW ShoudBeginEditing ( where object is inited or ViewDidLoad.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(updateActiveField:)
                                             name:@"UPDATE_ACTIVE_FIELD" object:nil];
```

Step2: Post a notification when ..ShouldBeginEditing with OBJECT of UITEXTFIELD or UITEXTVIEW

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UPDATE_ACTIVE_FIELD" 
                                                    object:textView];
return YES;
}
```

Step3: The method that (Step1 calles ) assigns the current UITEXTFIELD or UITEXTVIEW

```
-(void) updateActiveField: (id) sender {
    activeField = [sender object];
}
```

Step4: Add Keyboard observer UIKeyboardWillShowNotification  ( same place as Step1 )

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

and method:

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);

    _currentEdgeInsets = self.layoutPanel.contentInset; // store current insets to restore them later
    self.layoutPanel.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.layoutPanel.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    CGRect aRect =  self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGPoint p = [activeField convertPoint:activeField.bounds.origin toView:window];

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, p) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y +kbSize.height);
       [self.layoutPanel setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
       self.layoutPanel.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Step5: Add Keyboard observer UIKeyboardWillHideNotification ( same place as step 1 )

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and method:

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    self.layoutPanel.contentInset = _currentEdgeInsets;
    self.layoutPanel.scrollIndicatorInsets = _currentEdgeInsets;
    self.layoutPanel.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Remember to remove observers!

Answer (score 0):

I used this answer supplied by Sudheer Palchuri
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2873919/sudheer-palchuri
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32583809/6193496

In ViewDidLoad, register the notifications:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(DetailsViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(DetailsViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Add below observer methods which does the automatic scrolling when keyboard appears.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
textField.resignFirstResponder()
return true
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){

var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
keyboardFrame = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrame, fromView: nil)

var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){

var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution has 4 step:
- Step 1: the function listens when the keyboard appears

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Get the size of the keyboard.
CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
//top: 64 for navigation bar, 0 for without navigation
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0);
_scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
_scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

- Step 2: the function listens when the keyboard disappears

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
//top: 64 for navigatiob bar
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0);
[_editScrollView setContentInset: contentInsets];
[_editScrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets: contentInsets];
}
```

- Step 3: add these functions to the notification center:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

- Step 4: remove listen when view controller disappers

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```