# iOS: scrollView not scrolling to correct position when keyboard visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, keyboard

I am testing my iOS app using a 6.1 simulator.  I have been working for hours to scroll my scrollView to the correct position when a keyboard is visible (after a user clicks on a textView).  I have tried following the answer marked as correct on this page:

[How do I scroll the UIScrollView when the keyboard appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161666/how-do-i-scroll-the-uiscrollview-when-the-keyboard-appears)

This is what I currently have:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"keyboardWasShown");

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeView.frame.origin) ) {
        NSLog(@"scrollToView");
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.stepDescriptionField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        NSLog(@"scrollPoint: %f", scrollPoint.y);
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }

}
```

[image]

You can see from the images above that if the user clicks on the textView, the scrollView is not scrolled to the correct position (you should be able to see the text contents of the textView).

The strange thing is that I manually tried changing the y-offset of the scrollPoint to different values, but it seemed to have no effect on where the window scrolls to.  **What am I doing wrong?**

Other things that may be important:

- I have autolayout turned off (so that the user can scroll vertically in this view).
- the textView is not scrollable (it is resized to fit its contents)

**Edit**

I found that if I add my offset to the contentInsets as follows:

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height+50.0, 0.0);
```

the view will scroll to the correct position.  The only downside is that there is extra padding at the bottom:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I used this with a UITextField and not a UITextView but i believe it should still work the same.  This allows me to positions the textfield directly above the keyboard.

keyboardWillShow is the function when `NSNotificationCenter` receives `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
// Get the keyboard size
CGRect keyboardBounds;
[[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

// Start animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];


// Get Keyboard height and subtract the screen height by the origin of the textbox and height of text box to position textbox right above keyboard
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,keyboardBounds.size.height-([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - commentBox.frame.origin.y - commentBox.frame.size.height));

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```