# Scroll UIScrollView on selection UITextField, can't get the right sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

What I've got is a UIScrollView with a containerview inside it. This has a UITableViewcontroller embedded that contains static cells. I'd like to scroll the UIScrollView when I'm selecting a UITextField inside the static cells. I tried it two ways, 1. calculating the position, 2. calculating the cell index. Both ways I keep getting the same values when I'm selection an any UIField. Can someone help me to get this fixed?

I used this question:
[How do I scroll the UIScrollView when the keyboard appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161666/how-do-i-scroll-the-uiscrollview-when-the-keyboard-appears)

```
    func keyboardWasShown(notification : NSNotification){

        var info = notification.userInfo

//        var kbSize = info(UIKeyboa
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let kbSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: kbSize.height, right: 0)

                scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
                scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;


                //first approach
                println("---- approach 1 ------")
                var activeField = self.container?.groupField.superview?.superview
                println(activeField!.frame.origin)
                //prints (110.0, 5.0)



                //second approach
                println("---- approach 2 ------")
                var cell =  self.container?.groupField.superview?.superview as! UITableViewCell
                var table =  self.container?.view as! UITableView
                var index = table.indexPathForCell(cell)
                println("index: \(index?.row)") 
                //prints always 4



                var aRect = self.view.frame
                aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height
//                println("aRect: \(aRect)")
                if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin) ) {
                    println("ActiveField: \(activeField!.frame.origin.y)")
                    var scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField!.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height)
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated:true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake, I selected a default field as activefield

I replaced:
`var activeField = self.container?.groupField.superview?.superview`

to:
`var activeField = self.container?.activeField.superview?.superview`