# Detect when the keyboard is dismissed interactively

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller using both the standard keyboard and custom keyboard input + accessory views. I would like to update the accessory view state when a user drags to dismiss the input view (both keyboard and custom input).

Is there any way to detect when a dismissal is performed by the user, **specifically** through interactive drag to dismiss?

*(Note: this must be different from events triggered via programmatic dismissal of keyboard)*

Comment: check this answer maybe it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362987/how-to-detect-keyboard-frame-changes-when-dismiss-the-keyboard-interactively

Comment: @ChetanHedamba the linked question is a different problem (detecting frame changes during dismissal). That would be triggered for a dismissal that is cancelled (which is not desired), and I believe is also triggered by programmatic dismissal.