# TextField became collapse

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikeyboard

I have scrollview on which multiple text field are there. But when my KeyBoard shown my all text field and label collapse

```
 func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
            scroll.frame = CGRectMake(scroll.frame.origin.x, scroll.frame.origin.y, scroll.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 216)
        }

        func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {

            scroll.frame = CGRectMake(scroll.frame.origin.x, scroll.frame.origin.y, scroll.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**self.view.frame.size.height - 216)**

Did you notice this part in your this line

```
 scroll.frame = CGRectMake(scroll.frame.origin.x, scroll.frame.origin.y, scroll.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 216)
```

When you keyboard appears at that time you are changing the height of view. **And also don't check in simulator. Run on actual device.**

you need to handle it in proper way. for ex : [How do I scroll the UIScrollView when the keyboard appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161666/how-do-i-scroll-the-uiscrollview-when-the-keyboard-appears)