# Programmatically scroll ScrollView with StackView inside of it

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a `ScrollView` with a `StackView` inside of it. When the keyboard appears I am changing the `bottomConstraint` .

**1. view withouth keyboard**
**2. how it looks if keyboard shows**
**3. How it should look like**

[image] [image] [image]

The problem is that I would like to scroll the `ScrollView` a bit up but I can not make it work.

`scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), animated: true)` is **NOT** working. Ive tried it as you can see in the code but it has no effect:

**Keyboard Observer methods**

```
var keyboardHeight: CGFloat?
//MARK: keyboardObserver
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        self.keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

        if self.passwordWiederholenTextField.isEditing {
            scrollBottomViewConstraint.constant = -(self.keyboardHeight!)
            self.theScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20), animated: true)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        self.keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

        if self.passwordWiederholenTextField.isEditing {
            scrollBottomViewConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }
}
```

**Constraints:**

```
theScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
theScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
theScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
scrollBottomViewConstraint = theScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
scrollBottomViewConstraint.isActive = true

theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
theStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
stackViewBottomConstraint = theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.bottomAnchor)
stackViewBottomConstraint.isActive = true
```

I couldn't find anything on this so if anyone has any idea why it is not working I am very grateful!

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163543/3501225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Arun's tip I managed to get it done. This is my final code and it works perfectly:

```
var keyboardHeight: CGFloat?
//MARK: keyboardObserver
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        self.keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

        let activeField: UITextField? = [passwordTextField, passwordWiederholenTextField].first { $0.isFirstResponder }

        switch activeField {
        case passwordTextField:
            let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight! + 130, right: 0)
            theScrollView.contentInset = insets
            theScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        case passwordWiederholenTextField:
            let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight! + 30, right: 0)
            theScrollView.contentInset = insets
            theScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        default:
            break
        }

    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        self.keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

        theScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        theScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    }
}
```