# how to get position of UITextView in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitouch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableView and keyboard scrolling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-issue)

In have a `UIView` with in that I have its subview `UITableView` and on `UITableViewCells` I have `UITextView` where user can enter a text, now i want to get the **POSITION** of that **UITextView which is currently tapped by user.**

**UIToucheBegan** is **not calling** on **subviews** of a **UIView** means from **UITableView.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-issue

Comment: Do you mean screen position (x/y coordinates) or the index in the tableview?

Comment: @yinkou screen positions

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

1. Set your view controller as the UITextView delegate.
2. When editing begins, loop through the UITextView superviews until you find UITableViewCell.
3. Use the UITableViewCell frame property to determine its position (in conjunction with UITableView.contentOffset, UITableView.frame and your main container UIView.frame) to get the position of the UITextView relative the UIView (or whichever view you wanted).

or

1. Add a tap gesture recognizer to the UITableView.
2. In the target method, use `[tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:myTableView]` to get the tap relative the UITableView content.
3. Use the UITableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: method and then the cellForRowAtIndexPath: to get the UITableViewCell. From there, do (3) above.

Answer (score 0):

try add tag to the textField in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

and then in method which is calling when user start typing in UITextField look for sender.tag

or... may be it would be better to make CustomCell for this

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITableView and then implement  touchesBegan in that subclass if you want touches on tableview