# Keyboard overlapping TextField in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Enter Account Number and Enter Branch Id Textfields are working well at portrait mode when keyboard is appearing.I dissmiss it in Verify button as i don't get return key at Number pad.i do it programmatically.

[image]
But in landscape mode the keyboard is hidding my TextFields.What to do now?Any help is a blessing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, you can easily manage also. If the text fields are within the table view you can scroll the table view when the keyboard appears, if not you should embed the all the controls within a scroll view and scroll it. Use the keyboard notification to detect keyboard appearance and dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you register to receive the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, then you manually scroll the view to compensate.

pls refer this link

[Making a UITableView scroll when text field is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/uitableview-and-keyboard-scrolling-issue)