# Scroll the table view to the pop over-presenting text field when keyboard fires up by a text field inside the pop over

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with many cells, each cell contains four text fields vertical on each other, a pop over is presented by tapping on any text field, however, this pop over contains a text field when tapped the keyboard is fired and most likely the pop over will be shifted up to prevent the keyboard from hiding its text field (this is the default behavior of the pop over), but in the background (the dimmed view), the `tableViewController` loses its correct scrolling behavior to keep the pop over presenting-textField on the track while the keyboard is visible ..

a sample project [can be downloaded here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57066689/test57.zip).

how can I offset the table view to keep the pop over presenting-textField on screen while keyboard is visible in this case ?

I tried the well-known `TPKeyboardAvoiding` library but it didn't solve the issue.

p.s. `tableViewController` works well for the first 3 or 4 keyboard firings, but loses precise scrolling on later attempts.

**Screenshot** (the green text field is the text field which presented the pop over, but `tableViewController` scrolls to the incorrect text field indicated in red):
[image]

any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
this question is not a duplicate for: [Making a UITableView scroll when text field is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/making-a-uitableview-scroll-when-text-field-is-selected)
because the text field that I need the table view to scroll to is the one that fires a pop over not a keyboard, and `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` does not work precisely in this case because each cell contains 4 text fields.

Comment: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: @Astoria TPKeyboardAvoiding didn't solve the issue and I posted this question too on their github issues page.

Comment: Adjust manually maybe

Comment: I think you need to reduce the frame of tableview when keyboard appears and reset to full after keyboard disappears.

Answer (score 2):

use **(CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIView *)view** to get cell position on tableviews superview and accordingly handle the tableview offset

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution :
Change into 
**TableViewController.m**

**1.** Register for keyboard Notifications (`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`)

**2.** Create local variables:

```
CGSize _currentPopoverContentSize; //if you want to have custom size for popover

UIView *_currentPopoverSender; //to remember from wich view you will present popover

BOOL _keyboardIsShown; //enable in keyboardWillShow, and disable in keyboardWillHide
```

**3.** In my presentPopover method:

```
- (void)presentPopoverControllerWithSize:(CGSize)size fromView:(UIView *)sender{

MyController *controller = [[[MyController alloc] init] autorelease];

if (self.popover)
{
    [_popover release];
    _popover = nil;
}

_popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
_popover.popoverContentSize = size;
_popover.delegate = self;

//checking if keyboard is shown - if NO, than present popover, if YES - just `resignFirstResponder` for your _`activeTextField`(you can set it in -textFieldDidBeginEditing: and nullify in -textFieldDidEndEditing:)
if (!_keyboardIsShown)
{
    [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds]
                              inView:sender
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                            animated:YES];
    _popOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);

}
else
{
    [_activeTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

_currentPopoverContentSize = size;
_currentPopoverSender = sender;
}
```

**4.** Than:

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     //do some stuff
                  _popOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     if (_popover && _currentPopoverSender)
                     {
                         [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:[_currentPopoverSender bounds]
                                                   inView:_currentPopoverSender
                                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                 animated:YES];
                     }

                 }];

_keyboardIsShown = NO;
}
```

**5.**:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self presentPopoverControllerWithSize:textField.frame.size fromView:_activeText];

//     self.vc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductSourcePopOver"];
//
//    if(_popOver == nil){   //make sure popover isn't displayed more than once in the view
//        _popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:self.vc];
//    }
//    _popOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
//
//    [_popOver presentPopoverFromRect:_activeText.frame inView:_activeText permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
//    _popOver.delegate = self;

}
```

This might helps you :)

Comment: this is already implemented in my project, read the question carefully

Comment: Hi @JAHelia, I read the question carefully, tried to use this solution it would solved your problem :) Thanks.

Comment: give me a working sample project or reflect this on the attached project

Comment: download your sample project `test57` change into **TableViewController.m** file

Answer (score 0):

Change the entire view frame size.

For example, `keyboard height is 100` then,

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - keyboardHeight);
```

Then call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method again for the same `indexPath`, so it will reload the popover.

This is just a base idea, there might be some modifications required to achieve exact behavior.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

How about add the tag(00 01 02 03, 10 11 12 13...etc) for each UITextfield in the cell, From tens digit you can know which cell, from single digits you know which textfield.

Comment: i tried something like this but the problem not how to reach out to the textfield but how to offset the table view to match the text field

Answer (score 0):

Register for **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** and when that selector gets triggered, call your pop over code:

```
[self presentPopoverControllerWithSize:textField.frame.size fromView:_activeText];
```

The reason for this is that the iOS handles itself presenting the popover and handling it's frame. So it's generally a good practice to present the pop over after the keyboard is shown.

Hope this helps..