# How to scroll to a specific UITableViewCell top to UITableView top not center? (2 gifs to explain)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is what I want (cell top become at table top)

[image: wanted]

This is what is happening (cell top become at table center)

[image: unwanted]

I use this code

```
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2+numberOfComments, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView?.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
```

**EDIT :-** Extra info, the target cell is the last cell in the table.

Comment: I think you are not getting correct IndexPath of particular row that you want on top , 
so what is the condition when row should be visible on top?

Comment: Have you tested to see what happens if you try and scroll to the second or third cell in the table? this might tell you if scrolling the last cell to the top of the view is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a layout constraint for you tableview bottom and container view bottom, name it **botMargin** and set it equal **0**

[image: Imgur]

2. When the keyboard show, set **botMargin.constant = keyboardHeight**, and when the keyboard was hidden, set it back to 0

And this is the code to get the height of keyboard

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.onShowKeyboard(_:)), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.onHideKeyboard), name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil) 


func onShowKeyboard(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue()
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

    botMargin.constant = keyboardHeight
}

func onHideKeyboard() {
    botMargin.constant = 0
}
```

Comment: try scrolling to the final cell, where you don't have more space to sroll.

Comment: so you want to the last cell of tableview scroll to the top of tableview? why do you want to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: the last cell has a textfield, which show a keyboard, i don't want the keyboard to cover the textfield.

Comment: Haha, wait a minute, I will show you how to do that!

Comment: There're already tons of questions related to this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/making-a-uitableview-scroll-when-text-field-is-selected

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko : my question is different.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen maybe, I misunderstood something. You've just accepted the explanation how to handle keyboard appearance on a screen with a table view with a text field in a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this, First declare one `CGPoint` instance to store current `contentOffset` of tableview.

```
var lastScrollPoint = CGPoint()
```

Now use this code to scroll the tableview

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
let scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y)
self.lastScrollPoint = self.tableView.contentOffset;
self.tableView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
```

Now on `textFieldShouldReturn` set the scroll to default or the lastScroll

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(self.lastScrollPoint, animated: true)
    return true
}
```