# How to move the tableview up on click of a textview

Tags: swift, scroll, keyboard, tableview, uitextview

I have many `textfields` and one `textview` at the bottom of the form. All these are embedded in a tableview. I am able to move the `tableview` up on click of any `textfield`.

**Question:** How do I achieve the same for a `textview`. Any help would be appreciated.

The code that I used to move the `tableview` up on click of a `textfield` is this -

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

let txtFieldPosition = textField.convertPoint(textField.bounds.origin, toView: profileTableView)
        let indexPath = profileTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(txtFieldPosition)
        if indexPath != nil {
            profileTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
        }
return true
 }
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding it is the easiest way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2630476/3548469

Answer (score 0):

Make NotificationCenter for keyboard appear and disappear.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillAppear), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillDisappear), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Add two functions.

```
func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){
    //manage UI
}

func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification){
    //manage UI
}
```