# Make UITableView in UIViewController scroll to text fields

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've read here that if I have `UITextField` in my table cells, the table scrolls automatically to the cell that contains them. This works perfectly.
[Making a UITableView scroll when text field is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594181/making-a-uitableview-scroll-when-text-field-is-selected)

Is there a way to get this to work with a `UIViewController`? I'm using a `UIViewController` because I have a lot of custom UI that needs to be laid out on top of the table view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend splitting your viewController into several using containerViews.

That way, you can use a UITableViewController for your tableView and use a regular UIViewController for all the custom UI.

Another way would be to set a scrollView's contentOffset manually when a textField is in focus.

It would look something like that.

```
@IBAction func textField(didBeginEditing sender: UITextField) {
    let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: textField.frame.minY)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true) 
}
```